# Converting video to 320x240@30fps in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, video, avfoundation

In my iPhone app I would like to convert a video from the recorded format (HD) to a lower resolution (320x240) but I would like to maintain the 30fps frame rate.

I am currently converting using AVAssetExportPreset but the only available values are:

```
AVAssetExportPresetLowQuality
AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality
```

and

```
AVAssetExportPreset640x480
AVAssetExportPreset960x540
AVAssetExportPreset1280x720
AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
```

None of these seem to match my requirements. Low is getting close but the bitrate is very low and it forces the frame rate to 15fps which is no good.

If possible I would like to achieve this using hardware accelerated libraries.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for convert video in desired size and in desired quality.

Answer (score 0):

The camera may stop delivering frames if you hold onto buffers 
for too long. Thus, the sample buffer delegate’s callback must be fast.

Set the alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames property to YES 
(the default) for early, efficient dropping of late video frames

If you are using CoreGraphics and/or OpenGL during processing they both work well with ‘BGRA’.You can set the videoSettings property to specify a custom output format.